# GLIBC : How to tell the executable to link to specific version of GLIBC

Tags: c, linux, unix, glibc, libc

We are building a GTK3 application targeting Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and all the later releases. But when we build an application in Ubuntu version 20.04, that application can't run on the older Ubuntu releases. It says

> libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.31' not found (required by .source)

But if I build an application on Ubuntu 18.04, it will work on all the later Ubuntu releases. Ubuntu 18.04 has GLIBC version 2.27 by default and this version will work on all the later releases.

So is there any way to tell my application that, the application is built with GLIBC 2.27 irrespective of what version the OS in which the application is built has? Is there any way to feed this information of the GLIBC version to the application during the build process?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Binary compatibility is a harder problem than source compatibility. If you are going to distribute pre-built binaries then the usual approach is to build in the oldest environment you want the binary to support.  Sometimes that also means maintaining multiple binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to tell the executable to link to specific version of GLIBC

You *can't*.

The hack offered by Antonio Petricca (and elsewhere) is likely to introduce very subtle bugs, and is *ill-advised*.

The right way to fix this is to perform compile and link against the *minimal* version of GLIBC you need to run with. That could be done by

- building on an older system
- building in a `chroot` environment
- building in a docker container
- creating a Linux-to-older-Linux cross-compiler and using it to build the program.